# Symfony caches Twig templates in web folder

Tags: symfony, caching, twig

I had a clean Symfony 2.7.3 installation (now updated to 2.7.4). In the `app/cache/` folder, the normal cache files for prod and dev are written, but in the `/web/` folder there is a folder named `1` with several files in it (`web/1/3/7/37f3b66c84cbaf22abc4c5939452d2181eff0b0ec427c68c5499e3743849be17.php` for example).

They are cached Twig templates, but why are they stored there? How to get them into the common cache folder?

I use Windows with Xampp 1.8.2, but on several Linux servers it's the same, so it should not be a server or PHP problem. Hope anyone can tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Look at your twig config in `config.yml` and search for `cache`:

```
twig:  
    cache: "%kernel.cache_dir%/twig"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Cache was "true" so this is why it was the folder 1.